# Enable APIs using serviceusage API with a service account

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-auth-library

I want to create an automatic deployment of GCP for clients.

In order to do that, I have opened a page for them to login with google, and then enabled the IAM API and the Service Usage API.

Then I have created a service account that I want to use from this point forward in order to enable other required APIs on demand and not all at once.

When I try to enable the cloudkms API, I get

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/x-y-z/services/cloudkms.googleapis.com?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission"
```

I tried using the service account credentials (google.auth.jwt.Credentials) that I have created from the response of creating the service account, and I have added all the required permissions. I don't want to grant the role owner to the service account, because I want the account to have as less permissions as possible.

When I try to get the status of cloudkms API using the user's permissions, it works.

I have seen some solutions addressing me needing to create credentials for the service account here : https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials but I really need to do this programatically as well.

My code:

```
credentials = jwt.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_info['email'] + '.json', audience="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
# credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default() - it works with this
service_usage = googleapiclient.discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
service_usage.services().get(name="projects/<project_id>/services/cloudkms.googleapis.com").execute()
```

The error was mentioned above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need the Cloud IAM permission `serviceusage.services.enable` to enable services. Depending on what features your require, such as listing services, you need `serviceusage.services.list`.

Typically you add the role `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin` which includes the following permissions:

- serviceusage.services.get
- serviceusage.services.list
- serviceusage.services.enable
- serviceusage.services.disable

Comment: I actually used the roles/owner and added it to the policy, and put the service account under it, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

1. Goto IAM
2. Edit user selected
3. Add new rol
4. Type **Service Usage Admin**
5. Save

Comment: I had to scroll to it - didn't find it typing

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem. Using owner account had 403 error responses.
I had an `GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH` set up in my .env file and IDE pick up this file automatically. So basically was using one of the service accounts which haven't had required permissions